# subsorting html table with js

Tags: javascript, html

I have sorted my html table, and I wanted to do a subsort. cant seems to figure out what's wrong with my code, been stuck here for a while now.
I am trying to sort table on columns 4 then if there is any value identical sort them by id

```
let table = document.querySelector('tbody')
function sort() {

  let tr = table.children;
  let test1 = [...tr]
    .sort((a, b) => parseInt(b.children[3].innerHTML) - parseInt(a.children[3].innerHTML))
    .map(el => table.append(el));

  let test2 = [...tr]
    .sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.children[3].innerHTML === b.children[3].innerHTML)
          return parseInt(a.children[0].innerHTML) - parseInt(b.children[0].innerHTML)
      }
    })
.map(el => table.append(el));

};
```

```
==HTML==
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class='table_row'>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>jone</td>
            <td>170</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>josh</td>
            <td>170</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
            <td>adrian</td>
            <td>270</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>data4</td>
            <td>merry</td>
            <td>70</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML.

Comment: check your console as well

Comment: `return a.children[3].innerHTML - b.children[3].innerHTML || parseInt(a.children[0].innerHTML) - parseInt(b.children[0].innerHTML)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both property checks in the same sort function.  If you call a sort after another sort you will end up resorting your list and the original sort has no impact.  And that makes sense if you think about it.  Some pseudo code for what you’d want.  There are more compact/elegant ways but this illustrates what you’d do.  And if you understand doing two then you can do three etc etc.

```
function sort(a,b){
    const firstPropCompare = a.first - b.first;
    If(firstPropCompare != 0) return firstPropCompare;
    const secondCompare = a.second - b.second;
    return secondCompare;
}
```

Comment: yes it works, do you mind sharing the more elegant/compact way? I wanted to learn